# python regular expression specific characters, any combination

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to create a regex clause where it can detect any combination of **'ACTG'** characters, and accept that as valid. While anything else - including a combination of **'ACTG'** and some other characters are invalid.

Ultimately, I'll take it out of the while loop, that's just for testing purposes.  Right now I believe as long as it starts with either a, c, t, or g, it says it's valid....

Is there a funcition in regex that would be better suited than match?

```
import re
while (True):
    DnaString = str(input('enter your polynucleotide chain code hooblah'))
    if (re.match('([ACTG]+[ACTG]*)', DnaString, flags=0)):
        #if re.search('^ACTG', DnaString) != -1: 
            print ("valid chain.")
    else: #(re.search('^[ACTG]+[ACTG]*$', DnaString) == -1):
        print("invalid chain, please check your input.")

    if (DnaString.find("end") != -1):
        print("ohokaybye.")
        break
```

Comment: Does you code do what you want it to do?  Are you having trouble using `match()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just

```
if all(c in 'ACGT' for c in DnaString):
    # Do success
else:
    # Do failure
```

Comment: so much simpler! thank you.  all is still a reg ex function?

Comment: `all` returns `true` if every value in the iterable (in this case, the generator `(c in 'ACGT' for c in DnaString)`) evaluates to `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are just searching for the ACTG characters anywhere in the string without specifying that nothing else is permitted.
If you change your regex to `^[ACTG]+$` then it will work as expected. The ^ and $ characters are anchors which mean the start and end of the line, respectively.

So the regex above matches a string which contains one or more of the four characters and doesn't allow any other characters either before or after them.

Comment: i had tried that in the beginning! let me try again. Thanks!

Comment: edit: tried it, now works! not sure what changed in the middle.  now i have : (re.match('^([ACTG]+[ACTG]*)$', DnaString, flags=0))

Comment: That works, although the `[ACTG]*` isn't doing anything. The `[ACTG]+` is a greedy match for **one or more** of the four characters, which means that it matches as many as possible. After it has matched as many as possible, the `[ACTG]*` tries to match **zero or more** characters, finds zero (since they've already been matched by `+`) and finishes. So `^([ACTG]+)$` would work just as well

Answer (score 1):

If you allow a match to internally repeat acceptable characters, then this might be what you want:

```
'[A|C|T|G]{4}'
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to do the same as what i have now.  If it's in the first four indexes, then it works, but if another character is used later, it doesn't detect that it's invalid

Answer (score 0):

### Without regular expressions:

- Expanding on the original **Code Only** answer.
- Use the membership operator, [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)

  - Cretes a generator of `True` or `False` values
- Use the built-in python function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

  - Checks the generator, if they are `all` `True`, `True` is returned, otherwise `False`.
- Use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), e.g. `(base in bases for base in sequence)`

```py
bases = 'acgt'
sequence = (input('Input DNA sequence: ')).lower()

if all(base in bases for base in sequence):
    print('Input is correct')
else:
    print('Only allowed bases are A, T, C, G')
```

#### Output:

```py
Input DNA sequence:  atcgggggcccccttttaaaa
Input is correct

Input DNA sequence:  atcgggggcccccttttaaaaf
Only allowed characters are A, T, C, G
```

### Write a function:

- Considering the length of a DNA sequence, realistically, noone is going to type one in.

```py
def check_sequence(sequence: str):
    sequence = sequence.lower()
    bases = 'acgt'
    if all(base in bases for base in sequence):
        print('Input is correct')
    else:
        print('Only allowed characters are A, T, C, G')

my_sequence = 'gcaatgcAttGtgaaagagccGcTaCaacctaaacGctgcacgtcacctagagtgtCttgcgggTgaggccctctcgAacagattacagtaccgttatc'

check_sequence(my_sequence)

>>> Input is correct
```

### Function that returns the sequence if it's not correct:

- Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine iterables

```py
def check_sequence(sequence: str) -> list:
    sequence = [base for base in sequence.lower()]
    base_pairs = 'acgt'
    matches = list(bases in base_pairs for bases in sequence)

    sequence_check = list(zip(sequence, matches))

    if all(matches):
        print('Input is correct')
    else:
        print('Only allowed characters are A, T, C, G')
        return sequence_check
```

#### Usage:

```py
my_sequence = 'GcaatGcatfftgtgaaagAg'

verified_sequence = check_sequence(my_sequence)

print(verified_sequence)

# Output:
[('g', True),
 ('c', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('t', True),
 ('g', True),
 ('c', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('t', True),
 ('f', False),
 ('f', False),
 ('t', True),
 ('g', True),
 ('t', True),
 ('g', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('g', True),
 ('a', True),
 ('g', True)]
```